# Circle Geometry Questions

Tags: geometry, circles

In rectangle $ABCD$, we have $AD = 3$ and $AB = 4$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$, and let $X$ be the point such that $MD = MX$, $\angle MDX = 77^\circ$, and $A$ and $X$ lie on opposite sides of $\overline{DM}$. Find $\angle XCD$, in degrees.

[image: Diagram]

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Since $MC=MD=MX$, the points $C,X,D$ lie on a circle centered at $M$ and 
$$\widehat{XCD}=\frac{1}{2}\widehat{XMD} = \color{red}{13^\circ}.$$

Comment: Brilliant. Elegant.

Comment: +1 Nice. The title of the question gave it away for me :)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
It's easy to see MC=MD, hence points D X and C are located on a circle, with M being the center. Now, we know angle XCD is half of angle DMX (why?)

Answer (score 1):

Find the $\angle ADM$ from the right-angled triangle. This will help you find $\angle XDC$, as $\angle XDC = 77^{\circ} - \angle CDM = 77^{\circ} - 90^{\circ} + \angle ADM$. Then use Sine Theorem on $\triangle DMX$ to find the length of $\overline{DX}$ and then finally use Sine Theorem on $\triangle DXC$ to find $\angle XCD$.

This should be your outline for caclulating the value of the wanted angle. I leave the calculations to you.

Comment: The sine theorem is definitely an overkill here.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You're right, but that was the first thing that came to my mind. Anyway nice solution.